# Typescript Map Relation with Array objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary

Accordint to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

initializing a Map from an array like this is legitimate:

```
let kvArray = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
let myMap: Map<string, string> = new Map(kvArray);
```

Despite, my Visual Studio Code compiler complains with this:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, string]>): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, string]>'.
The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you havn't put a type on `kvArray`, so typescript is inferring it. It infers that it's a `string[][]`, but that's not specific enough. The Map constructor needs [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) with exactly two strings, not arrays with an arbitrary number of strings. Your javascript is creating these tuples, but you'll need to be explicit about the types:

```
let kvArray: [string, string][] = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
```

Comment: That, indeed, makes the compiler happy. Thanks. (Strange declaration syntax, though).